# Link each product to its product_details page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In native PHP it takes about 2 minutes to link each product on the page to its product_details page

-- like gives each products an id from the database, and in the details page grab the id from the URL by $_GET and fetch the database info for the same id

Now I am stack doing the same thing in Laravel, can anyone give me hand here please

Here is my code

The route **Route Edit**

```
Route::get('Current_projects', 'ProjectController@currentProjects');
Route::get('projects/projectDetails/{id}', 'ProjectController@viewProject');
```

Here is my controller

```
class ProjectController extends \BaseController
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function currentProjects()
    {
        $projects = Projects::all();
        return View::make('projects.currentProjects', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }

    public function viewProject($id)
    {
        $projects = Projects::with('projectDetails')->findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('projects.currentProjects.projectDetails', compact($projects));
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to link **Edit**

```
<a href="{{ URL::to("projects/projectDetails/{$pro->id}") }}" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
```

Now when I click on any product in the currentProjects

Got Error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Open: C:\wamp\www\myPro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php
```

**php artisan route**

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                      | Name | Action                            | Before Filters | After Filters |

+--------+------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                               |      | PagesController@home              |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD home                            |      | PagesController@home              |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD about                           |      | PagesController@about             |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD vision                          |      | PagesController@vision            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD Chairman Word                   |      | PagesController@chairmanWord      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD contacts                        |      | PagesController@contacts          |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD Current_projects                |      | ProjectController@currentProjects |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD project/projectDetails/{id} |      | ProjectController@viewProject     |                |               |
+--------+------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: look at the route definition in my answer.

Comment: @lagbox do you mean this `URL::to("projects/projectDetails/{$pro->id}");` I try but same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="{{ url('projects/projectDetails', [$pro->id]) }}"> ... </a>
```

for more check this link
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Answer (score 0):

NotFoundHttpException is like HTTP 404 - Site not found. It seems that something is with your routing or your link wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a URL to a route you haven't defined.

Routes match URIs. There is no route defined for `Current_projects/projectDetails/{id}`.

Also this is incorrect:

```
Route::get('projects/projectDetails/{$id}', ...);
```

Params don't have `$` signs in them in the URI.

```
Route::get('projects/projectDetails/{id}', ...);
```

Would be the correct way to define that.

Then you can create a URL to that:

```
URL::to("projects/projectDetails/{$pro->id}");
```

Comment: See my updated question I have the Route there. by the you are right I left the `$` by mistake

Comment: why are you randomly adding `URI:` to your route definition, do you see that in my definition?

Comment: my new Route `Route::get('URI:project/projectDetails/{id}', 'ProjectController@viewProject');`

Comment: why are you randomly adding `URI:` to that?  `Route::get('projects/projectDetails/{id}', ...);` there is no `URI:` there

Comment: I didn't get you right How I'm randomly adding `URI: ` to route? and how can I do it the right way?

Comment: I am sorry I just understood what you mean, that is way I deleted my comment.
Now I made my route : `Route::get('project/projectDetails/{id}', 'ProjectController@viewProject');` forgive me I new bit to this so I am very confused.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Update your original question with the current state of what you have so others will be able to answer based on your current information.

Comment: I did Edit my question Edit `Route` and `URL` in my question